# Getting Twitter rate limit information

Tags: ruby, twitter

I am using the [Twitter Gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/) to perform some searches using Twitter's 1.1 API and I'd like to get some examples on how to query my current rate limit information.

I've found the [class documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/RateLimit) but it's not clear to me how to query this info. I have done the following :

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'twitter'

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
#... omitting connection info ....
end

rate_info = Twitter::RateLimit.new
tweets = client.search('obama -rt', lang: 'en', result_type: 'recent').take(3)
# Do stuff with tweets

puts "Limit is #{rate_info.limit}"
```

but the "rate_info.limit" is null; I would think I need to somehow "link" my client object to the RateLimit object. How can I best query this info using the Twitter Gem?